Specify input for raster function in ModelBuilder
Inside my model I want to generate a raster from a raster function.
Where and how do I specify the input raster for the function?
I assume you write something in the value next to raster, but the syntax with % that normally grabs variables in ModelBuilder doesn't work here.
This is how the dialog looks inside ModelBuidler:

This is how the dialog looks in the raster function pane:


Sky view factor properties appears not to be a standard tool in ArcPro. If this is a third party tool you should contact the author of it.

that will probably be my next step, but I have the same problem with other Raster Functions which are included in Pro from the start.

I figured out the solution, but because the question is closed I can't post an actual answer, but maybe someone with the same porblem finds this.
To get the raster into the raster function one must put down the whole path to the raster file instead of just the variable name. So instead of %DGM_plus_Buildings% I put %Workspace%\DGM_plus_Buildings.tif
